# I am not able to update TexStudio in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, latex

After opening TexStudio I got a message to update from version  2.8.4 to 2.9.4. After downloading the needed package, Ubuntu Software Center opens and it says that:

```
Breaks in the package texstudio-dbg dependency texstudio(=2.8.4+debian-3)
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1st, read [this](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/#download):**

> ### Linux
>
> We recommend that you first **try** to install TeXstudio from the
>   repository of your distribution. Only if TeXstudio is not available
>   there, use the following pre-packaged versions.

`texstudio-dbg 2.8.4` needs `texstudio 2.8.4`, but you installed 2.9.4

Normally you do not need debug packages.

---

**2nd, if you insist on 2.9.4, use the following steps:**

1. Remove the `texstudio-dbg`

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove texstudio-dbg
   ```
2. Install your `.deb` file again:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i texstudio_2.9.4_amd64.deb
   ```

Comment: Does this get rid of user settings like colour themes etc?

Answer (score 0):

**Install from Ubuntu Software center**
You just need to search TeXstudio in software center and click on the install button.

[image]

For other methods visit this [page](https://www.ubuntupit.com/how-to-install-texstudio-a-latex-editor-in-ubuntu-linux/)